# Problem with BEGIN/END_MESSAGE_MAP in my Visual Studio 2022 MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I get the following errors in my MFC Project:
(Please note: the bolded lines matches the title of my Error List in Visual Studio 2022)

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State**

Error (active)  E1086   the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "CappApp::GetThisMessageMap"    app C:\Projects\C++Projects\app\app.cpp 21

Error   C2662   'const AFX_MSGMAP *CappApp::GetThisMessageMap(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const CappApp' to 'CappApp &' app C:\Projects\C++Projects\app\app.cpp 21

Error   C1189   #error:  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]    main    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\atlmfc\include\afx.h  24

The last Error comes from an Error Directive, which prints the error as followed by C1189 into my error list. I ignored this in the past (because the program still executed), but I am in additional trouble with error C1086 and C1189. I don't know how to handle this.
Could you please help?

This is the code from  my MFC project

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CappApp, CWinAppEx)
    // Standard file based document commands
//  ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_NEW, &CWinAppEx::OnFileNew)
//  ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_OPEN, &CWinAppEx::OnFileOpen)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Please note: The lines ON_COMAND ... I commented out, because I am not using the MFC menu, but if I don't the following messages show:

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State**

Error   C2248   'CWinApp::OnFileOpen': cannot access protected member declared in class 'CWinApp'   app C:\Projects\C++Projects\app\app.cpp 24
Error   C2248   'CWinApp::OnFileNew': cannot access protected member declared in class 'CWinApp'    app C:\Projects\C++Projects\app\app.cpp 23

Also: in case I would comment out BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP until and including END_MESSAGE_MAP, I would obtain these error messages:

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State**

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct AFX_MSGMAP const * __cdecl CappApp::GetMessageMap(void)const " (?GetMessageMap@CappApp@@UEBAPEBUAFX_MSGMAP@@XZ)  app C:\Projects\C++Projects\app\app.obj 1

Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  app C:\Projects\C++Projects\app\x64\Debug\app.exe   1

The following is the code I need fixed in order to go ahead with my efforts:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CappApp, CWinAppEx)
    // Standard file based document commands
    //ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_NEW, &CWinAppEx::OnFileNew)
    //ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_OPEN, &CWinAppEx::OnFileOpen)
END_MESSAGE_MAP
```

These macros are defined in winafx.h as follows:

```
#define DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP() \
protected: \
    static const AFX_MSGMAP* PASCAL GetThisMessageMap(); \
    virtual const AFX_MSGMAP* GetMessageMap() const override; \

#define BEGIN_TEMPLATE_MESSAGE_MAP(theClass, type_name, baseClass)          \
    PTM_WARNING_DISABLE                                                     \
    template < typename type_name >                                         \
    const AFX_MSGMAP* theClass< type_name >::GetMessageMap() const          \
        { return GetThisMessageMap(); }                                     \
    template < typename type_name >                                         \
    const AFX_MSGMAP* PASCAL theClass< type_name >::GetThisMessageMap()     \
    {                                                                       \
        typedef theClass< type_name > ThisClass;                            \
        typedef baseClass TheBaseClass;                                     \
        __pragma(warning(push))                                             \
        __pragma(warning(disable: 4640)) /* message maps can only be called by single threaded message pump */ \
        static const AFX_MSGMAP_ENTRY _messageEntries[] =                   \
        {

#define BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(theClass, baseClass) \
    PTM_WARNING_DISABLE \
    const AFX_MSGMAP* theClass::GetMessageMap() const \
        { return GetThisMessageMap(); } \
    const AFX_MSGMAP* PASCAL theClass::GetThisMessageMap() \
    { \
        typedef theClass ThisClass;                        \
        typedef baseClass TheBaseClass;                    \
        __pragma(warning(push))                            \
        __pragma(warning(disable: 4640)) /* message maps can only be called by single threaded message pump */ \
        static const AFX_MSGMAP_ENTRY _messageEntries[] =  \
        {

#define END_MESSAGE_MAP() \
        {0, 0, 0, 0, AfxSig_end, (AFX_PMSG)0 } \
    }; \
        __pragma(warning(pop))  \
        static const AFX_MSGMAP messageMap = \
        { &TheBaseClass::GetThisMessageMap, &_messageEntries[0] }; \
        return &messageMap; \
    }                                 \
    PTM_WARNING_RESTORE
// This is the end of BEGIN/END_MESSAGE_MAP in AfxWin.h
// =====================================================
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Here is the additional code, requested by Min Xin Yu:

```
enter code here
// lc.cpp : Defines the class behaviors for the application.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "afxwinappex.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "app.h"
#include "MainFrm.h"
#include "appDoc.h"
#include "appView.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CappApp
//  const AFX_MSGMAP* PASCAL GetThisMessageMap();

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CappApp, CWinApp)
//ON_COMMAND(ID_APP_ABOUT, &CappApp::OnAppAbout)
//// Standard file based document commands
//ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_NEW, &CWinApp::OnFileNew)
//ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_OPEN, &CWinApp::OnFileOpen)
//// Standard print setup command
//ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT_SETUP, &CWinApp::OnFilePrintSetup)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CappApp construction
CappApp::CappApp() noexcept{

// support Restart Manager
m_dwRestartManagerSupportFlags =      
                         AFX_RESTART_MANAGER_SUPPORT_ALL_ASPECTS;
#ifdef _MANAGED
// If the application is built using Common Language Runtime             
// support (/clr):
//     1) This additional setting is needed for Restart Manager 
//        support to work properly.
//     2) In your project, you must add a reference to 
//        System.Windows.Forms in order to build.
          System::Windows::Forms::Application::
SetUnhandledExceptionMode(System
::Windows::Forms::UnhandledExceptionMode::ThrowException);
#endif

// TODO: replace application ID string below with unique ID 
//string; 
// recommended ormat for string is 
// CompanyName.ProductName.SubProduct.VersionInformation
SetAppID(_T("lc.AppID.NoVersion"));

// TODO: add construction code here,
// Place all significant initialization in InitInstance
}

// The one and only CappApp object

CappApp theApp;


// CappApp initialization

BOOL CappApp::InitInstance() {
// InitCommonControlsEx() is required on Windows XP if an 
// application
// manifest specifies use of ComCtl32.dll version 6 or later to 
// enable
// visual styles.  Otherwise, any window creation will fail.
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
// Set this to include all the common control classes you want to 
// use in your application.
InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

CWinApp::InitInstance();


// Initialize OLE libraries
if (!AfxOleInit()) {
    AfxMessageBox(IDP_OLE_INIT_FAILED);
return FALSE;
}

AfxEnableControlContainer();

EnableTaskbarInteraction(FALSE);

// AfxInitRichEdit2() is required to use RichEdit control
// AfxInitRichEdit2();

// Standard initialization
// If you are not using these features and wish to reduce the 
// size
// of your final executable, you should remove from the following
// the specific initialization routines you do not need
// Change the registry key under which our settings are stored
// TODO: You should modify this string to be something 
// appropriate
// such as the name of your company or organization
SetRegistryKey(_T("Local AppWizard-Generated Applications"));
LoadStdProfileSettings(4);  // Load standard INI file options 
                            // (including MRU)


// Register the application's document templates.  Document 
// templates
//  serve as the connection between documents, frame windows and 
// views
CSingleDocTemplate* pDocTemplate;
pDocTemplate = new CSingleDocTemplate(
IDR_MAINFRAME,
RUNTIME_CLASS(CappDoc),
RUNTIME_CLASS(CMainFrame),       // main SDI frame window
RUNTIME_CLASS(CappView));
if (!pDocTemplate)
    return FALSE;
AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);

// Parse command line for standard shell commands, DDE, file open
CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);



// Dispatch commands specified on the command line.  Will return 
// FALSE if app was launched with /RegServer, /Register, 
// /Unregserver or /Unregister.
if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
    return FALSE;

// The one and only window has been initialized, so show and 
// update it
m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();
return TRUE;
}

int CappApp::ExitInstance()
  {
//TODO: handle additional resources you may have added
AfxOleTerm(FALSE);

return CWinApp::ExitInstance();
}

// CappApp message handlers


// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

//class CAboutDlg : public CDialogEx
//{
//public:
//  CAboutDlg() noexcept;
//
//  // Dialog Data
//#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
//  enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };
//#endif
//
//protected:
//  virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    
// DDX/DDV support
//
//  // Implementation
//protected:
//  DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
//};
//
//CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() noexcept : CDialogEx(IDD_ABOUTBOX)
//{
//}
//
//void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
//{
//  CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
//}
//
//BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialogEx)
//END_MESSAGE_MAP()
//
//// App command to run the dialog
//void CappApp::OnAppAbout()
//{
//  CAboutDlg aboutDlg;
//  aboutDlg.DoModal();
//}

// CappApp message handlers
```

This was the .cpp file, if needed I also deliver the .h file.
Thank you.

Comment: Why is this tagged for the Mac?

Comment: Sorry,  I made a mistake.  This is for the windows based visual studio.

Comment: The visual studio version is 2022

Comment: From the error: you are using /MD[d] and MFC in a static library which is conflicting.

Comment: Yes, that was my thought as well, but I have no idea how to fix this. Do you think you could give me a hint?

Comment: In project's properties->Advanced->Use of MFC-> Use MFC in a shared library.

Comment: I tried without success. In case I used Standard Windows libraries I got the following:
Severity Code

Error (active) E0035

Error (active) E1086

Message lnt-uninitialized-local

Error C1189

Error C1189

Comment: These are the errors, when changing to use MFC in shared libraries:
Severity Code Description
Message  Conversion loses qualifiers
Message  see declaration of 'CappApp::GetThisMessageMap'
Message  while trying to match the argument list '()'
Error C2662 'const AFX_MSGMAP *CappApp::GetThisMessageMap(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const CappApp' to 'CappApp &'
Error (active) E1086 the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "CappApp::GetThisMessageMap"

Comment: I consider above disturbing, because this is MFC code, only, nothing where I had made changes.

Comment: Is there class CWinAppEx ? From your error, it is CWinApp. And can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Do you have a `DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()` within the class definition in your application object's header file?

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson: Yes, I do.

Comment: @Minxin Yu: Please check my question again, my code is included. Sorry for the delayed reply.

Comment: I tested your app class, and it compiled well.

Comment: These are the errors staying with my attempts to build the application:
Severity Code Description
Error C1189 #error:  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]
Error LNK1266 error reading instrumentation file 'C:\Projects\C++Projects\app\x64\Debug\app.pgd'; File not found
Message lnt-uninitialized-local Local variable is not initialized.
Error MSB6006 "link.exe" exited with code 1266. 
Any comments?

Comment: @Minxin Yu: How could you compile the app? No header file, no ...

Comment: Create a new MFC SDI template with MFC standard named `app`.

[![image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TewFc.png)

Replace the code of the app.cpp file with your code.
Build the project.

Done.

Please complete your MFC project based on steps above.

Comment: @Minxin Yu:
These are remaining problems:
Severity Code Description
Error LNK1266 error reading instrumentation file 'C:\Projects\C++Projects\app\x64\Debug\app.pgd'; File not found
Message lnt-uninitialized-local Local variable is not initialized.

And also, in case the original app.cpp did compile on your system, why create a new app file. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: @Minxin Yu: I did what you suggested. Could you  help me with the remainder of my problems, please.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal project via GitHub that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Please give me some time, I never did this before. Possibly I will post all my code, because I have no idea, which code to eliminate in order to have a compiling project.

Comment: Sorry, I did not do that. I believe I found out what is going wrong. It is some include file logic and I will inquire in another StackOverflow question. Thank you for bearing with me, all answers are appreciated and useful.

Comment: Please see my include logic question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76922995/include-file-logic